# httpclient.GetStringAsync blocking

Tags: vb.net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, asynchttpclient

I must be doing something wrong since this code is blocking and runs synchronously, inspite of calling the `async` method of `GetStringAsync`. Any help would really help me understand the reasons:

```
Private Async Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim urls As List(Of String) = SetUpURLList()
    Dim baseAddress = New Uri("http://www.amazon.com")
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10
    Dim requestNumber As Integer = 0
    For Each url In urls
        requestNumber += 1
        Console.WriteLine("Request #:{0}", requestNumber)
        Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
        Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler With {.CookieContainer = cookies, _
                                                   .UseCookies = True}
        Dim httpClient = New HttpClient(handler) With {.BaseAddress = baseAddress}
        Dim response As String = Await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(False)
        For Each cook As Cookie In cookies.GetCookies(baseAddress)
            Console.WriteLine(cook.Name & "=" & cook.Value)
        Next
        httpClient.Dispose()
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it's blocking on the `GetStringAsync` call?

Comment: When I give a breakpoint at Dim response As String = Await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(False), then the code  breaks the first time, then on playing it, I was expecting it to again break for the second GetAsyn url and in this way break till the first or any asyn call returns. Thats not happening, it breaks at the above line and on executing, it completes the above line and then moves on the next line and after completing the entire of the loop, it goes into the second url and breaks on the line again.

Comment: Also, have seen only one TCP port getting created, closed and then again created and so on as the loop moves.

Comment: Have put some start stop line prints, here is  the result. Looks pretty synchronous.... Request #:1 started at:1:53:46 AM
Request #:1 ended at:1:53:50 AM
Request #:2 started at:1:53:50 AM
Request #:2 ended at:1:53:53 AM
Request #:3 started at:1:53:53 AM
Request #:3 ended at:1:53:56 AM
Request #:4 started at:1:53:56 AM
Request #:4 ended at:1:53:58 AM
Request #:5 started at:1:53:58 AM
Request #:5 ended at:1:54:01 AM
Request #:6 started at:1:54:01 AM
Request #:6 ended at:1:54:04 AM
Request #:7 started at:1:54:04 AM
Request #:7 ended at:1:54:06 AM

Comment: @Kallol It isn't blocking. It's asynchronously waiting using `await`. It's sequential. If you want it to be concurrent create a task for each url that represents the asynchronous operation and use `Task.WhenAll` to `await` for all theses tasks at once.

Comment: @l3aron thx for your response. I am sure you are meaning that multiple (in this case case 10) URLs will be fired asynchronously and each of them would return once they are complete because of the await and execute the rest of the method. Shouldnt then I see atleast 10 open TCP connections for this process? I dont, I just see one connection, the next connection gets created only once the first connection is closed. If 10 URLs will be fired based on ServiceManager, then surely I should see at least open ports more than 1 at any point of time?

Comment: @Kallol You shouldn't see more than 1 open connection since you are waiting for that operation to complete before moving on to the next. You are not blocking a thread while doing so and your app should still be responsive since you are using `async-await` but it's still serial. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't blocking, it's just sequential. You are firing each `Async` operation and asynchronously waiting for it to complete with `Await` before starting the next one.

If you want to fire all these operations concurrently first create a task for each `url` and then `Await` all these tasks at once using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
Dim semaphore As New SemaphoreSlim(10)
Async Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim urls As List(Of String) = SetUpURLList()
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10
    Dim tasks As List(Of Task) = new List(Of Task)()
    For Each url In urls
        tasks.Add(GetUrlAsync(url))
    Next
    Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
End Sub

Async Function GetUrlAsync(url As String) As Task
    Await semaphore.WaitAsync()
    Dim baseAddress = New Uri("http://www.amazon.com")
    Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
    Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler With {.CookieContainer = cookies, _
                                               .UseCookies = True}
    Dim httpClient = New HttpClient(handler) With {.BaseAddress = baseAddress}
    Dim response As String = Await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(False)
    For Each cook As Cookie In cookies.GetCookies(baseAddress)
        Console.WriteLine(cook.Name & "=" & cook.Value)
    Next
    httpClient.Dispose()
    semaphore.Release()
End Sub
```

<sup>*I hope this code makes sense, since I'm not really familiar with VB.Net.</sup>

Comment: Thx l3arnon. This is async and multiple ports are getting opened now. I thought GetStringAsync also returns a task, and hence didnt create an explicit task. Looks like I got the concept wrong. BTW, am noticing more than 10 connections getting open at once. DefaultMaxConnections was supposed to throttle at 10. Its not working - any ideas? If I write my custom throttler using Semaphoreslim, will I be able to use WhenAll?

Comment: @Kallol Yes. `SemaphoreSlim` would be better for throttling. Use it inside `GetUrl` and you can still use `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: @Kallol `GetStringAsync` does return a `Task`. the difference here is when are you using `Await`. You used `Await` on each separate `Task` while this uses `Await` once on all the tasks combined.

Comment: @l3arnon. Thx for the await explaination - I understand the mistake now. Also will post the semaphore code below

Comment: @Kallol I've added the `SemaphoreSlim` to the answer. Don't use `Wait()`, use `WaitAsync()` instead.

Comment: Thx @l3arnon, since am new here, not sure if I should use this thread for another question on the same code, hence created another new question. Would be helpful, if you find some time to look into it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726835/cancellation-not-returning-past-whenall-using-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code now - thx to @l3arnon for fire all and wait up on all completion.

```
Dim concurrencySemaphore As New SemaphoreSlim(10)
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim urls As List(Of String) = SetUpURLList()
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10 'Not working strangely
    Dim tasks As List(Of Task) = New List(Of Task)()
    For Each url In urls
        tasks.Add(GetUrl(url))
    Next
    Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
End Sub
Async Function GetUrl(url As String) As Task
    concurrencySemaphore.Wait()
    Dim baseAddress = New Uri("http://www.amazon.com")
    Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
    Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler With {.CookieContainer = cookies, _
                                               .UseCookies = True}
    Dim httpClient = New HttpClient(handler) With {.BaseAddress = baseAddress}
    Dim response As String = Await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(False)
    For Each cook As Cookie In cookies.GetCookies(baseAddress)
        Console.WriteLine(cook.Name & "=" & cook.Value)
    Next
    httpClient.Dispose()
    concurrencySemaphore.Release()
End Function
```