# Cancellation not returning past whenall using httpclient

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient, tpl-dataflow, asynchttpclient

Here is an updated version of the code posted under [httpclient.GetStringAsync blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725306/httpclient-getstringasync-blocking/27726366#27726366)

The question is when cancel is done, though the tasks are cancelled, I am expecting `Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` to return and print whats in `finally`, but its not. I can see task cancellations when pressing cancel and I also see the connections reduce to 0, but the finally guessing `WhenAll` still thinks some tasks are being executed.

Here is the code:

```
Private concurrencySemaphore As New SemaphoreSlim(10)
Private cts As CancellationTokenSource
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        cts = New CancellationTokenSource
        Dim urls As List(Of String) = SetUpURLList()
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10
        Dim tasks As List(Of Task) = New List(Of Task)()
        For Each url In urls
            cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
            tasks.Add(GetUrl(url, cts.Token))
        Next
        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
    Catch tx As TaskCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled")
    Catch ox As OperationCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine("Operation was cancelled")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Console.WriteLine("Done")
    End Try
End Sub
Async Function GetUrl(url As String, ByVal ct As CancellationToken) As Task
    Try
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        Await concurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync()
        Dim baseAddress = New Uri("http://www.amazon.com")
        Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
        Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler With {.CookieContainer = cookies, _
                                                   .UseCookies = True}
        Dim httpClient = New HttpClient(handler) With {.BaseAddress = baseAddress}
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        Dim responseMessage As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(url, ct).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Dim response As String = Await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        For Each cook As Cookie In cookies.GetCookies(baseAddress)
            Console.WriteLine(cook.Name & "=" & cook.Value)
        Next
        httpClient.Dispose()
        concurrencySemaphore.Release()
    Catch tx As TaskCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled Exception")
    Catch ox As OperationCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine("Operation Cancelled Exception")
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    If cts IsNot Nothing Then
        cts.Cancel()
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**
Have changed the question based on @I3arnon suggestion.

But 3 problems in the code below now:

```
 Dim downLoader As TransformBlock(Of String, Task(Of String))
 Dim cts As CancellationTokenSource
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    cts = New CancellationTokenSource
    Dim urls As List(Of String) = SetUpURLList()
    Dim tasks As List(Of Task) = New List(Of Task)()
    downLoader.Post(urls(0))
    downLoader.Post(urls(1))
    'For Each url In urls
    '    tasks.Add(downLoader.Post(url))
    'Next
End Sub

Private Sub TPL_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    downLoader = New TransformBlock(Of String, Task(Of String))(
    Async Function(url) As Task(Of String)
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading URL:{0}", url)
        Dim httpClient = New HttpClient()
        Using responseMessage As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(False)
            Dim response As String = Await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            Return response
            Console.WriteLine("Downloaded, URL:{0}, length:{1}", url, response.Length)
        End Using
    End Function, New ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, .CancellationToken = cts.Token})
End Sub
```

1. Code doesnt compile as I am not sure where to the `TransformBlock` signature and body. Putting it inside `load` is resulting in a null exception when it is being called since the object is not created.
2. How to we now fire the multiple URLs in parallel
3. How do we ensure cancellations, now that the `CancellationToken` is passed to the extension but not the inner method that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't release the semaphore when there's an exception (or cancellation in your case). That means `Task.WhenAll` is waiting for tasks that will never complete since they are waiting for that semaphore.

Move the semaphore's release to a `Finally` block to make sure it's never skipped:

```
Async Function GetUrl(url As String, ByVal ct As CancellationToken) As Task
    Try
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        Await concurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync()
        Dim baseAddress = New Uri("http://www.amazon.com")
        Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
        Dim handler As New HttpClientHandler With {.CookieContainer = cookies, _
                                                   .UseCookies = True}
        Dim httpClient = New HttpClient(handler) With {.BaseAddress = baseAddress}
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        Dim responseMessage As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(url, ct).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Dim response As String = Await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        For Each cook As Cookie In cookies.GetCookies(baseAddress)
            Console.WriteLine(cook.Name & "=" & cook.Value)
        Next
        httpClient.Dispose()
    Catch tx As TaskCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled Exception")
    Catch ox As OperationCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine("Operation Cancelled Exception")
    Finally
        concurrencySemaphore.Release()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Your `httpClient` is declared inside the scope of the Try body. It is not accessible inside Finally.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy true. Updated.

Comment: Thank you, yes its returning now. But now there is a problem with cancellation. The URL list has 5000 URLs. All these get queued as tasks but wait for semaphore to execute. When I press cancel, the executing tasks (10 of them as per the semaphore), gets cancelled. However the rest that were queued is also cancelled one at a time resulting into a 60 seconds wait after cancel is pressed. Are there any other options to allow for faster cancellations? I could have more than 5000 URLs to run too and that would create a longer wait for cancellation even though my concurrency would be only max of 50.

Comment: @Kallol You should probably use TPL Dataflow for that. Create an `ActionBlock` that works on each url and post all urls to it. You can set a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` instead of using a semaphore and pass a `CancellationToken`. You wait for it to complete with `Await block.Completion` and if you cancel the token it stops immediately.

Comment: @I3arnon thanks, made an attempt but ran up into issues. Do have a look pls on the updated question

Comment: @Kallol You don't need TransformBlock since you're not returning anything, use ActionBlock. The inner method doesn't return Task(Of String) but Task for the same reason. You don't need to create the block in a different method. You can do that in Button1_Click. Passing the token to the block makes sure it won't process any more urls. If you want to cancel currently running iterations you need to pass the cancellation token yourself.

Comment: @I3arnon, I do need the contents of the page, and hence a return of string would be necessary. For this (sorry, didnt find a better way to paste code) in comments...  Dim downLoader As New TransformBlock(Of String, String)(
        Async Function(url)
            Return Await New HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(False)
        End Function, New ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4})............... I am getting a compiler error "Async modified can only be used on Subs, or on functions that return a Task or Task(Of T). Any ideas would be appreciated pls.

Comment: @Kallol you're function doesn't probably doesn't return a Task, or Task(Of String)